# pyinstaller: how to handle unecessary dependencies using pip?

Tags: python, pandas, pip

I have a question about how pip handles python dependencies as opposed to conda. If I do the following:

`pip install pandas`

This will install both `pandas` and `numpy` into my current environment. However if I do:

- Why does the command install `numpy`? Why is `pip` taking care of dependencies for me?

This is important because I am trying to "lighten" a `pyinstaller` compilation. I have a small program which uses limited `pandas` functionality for which I do not need all dependencies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well just make a pip uninstall numpy and run then pyinstaller if you're convinced, that numpy is not needed.

Normally pip installs all dependencies, that are listed as necessary dependencies in the package description.

To understand the dependencies look at the source code of pandas: https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas

Look at the file `setup.py` ( https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/master/setup.py )

You will find following lines:

```
"install_requires": [
    "python-dateutil >= 2.6.1",
    "pytz >= 2017.2",
    "numpy >= {numpy_ver}".format(numpy_ver=min_numpy_ver),
],
```

This is why pip installs numpy. pandas says, that it requires numpy, so pip follows these instructions.

If uninstalling numpy and running pyinstaller won't work, then you might post a separate question to ask how to convince pyinstaller to not include a package.

Pyinstaller has for some packages some default dependencies configured (as far as I know) There's probably a way to override it.